# Image won't resize in height when it shrinks in width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an image in a `div` which can be of various resolutions. If I have a wider image with low height (ex. 730x90) it doesn't show properly on mobile. It shrinks in width but the height remains the same. Here's the code (I'm writing CSS in JS using React so that's valid code, the exact synthax isn't the problem here). `child` is a `span` which only contains a single `img` inside.

```
    parent: {
        '@media(max-width:744px)': {
            minWidth: '100vw',
        },
        '@media(max-height:823px)': {
            minHeight: 'auto',
        }
    },
    child: {
        '@media(max-width:744px)': {
            maxWidth: '80vw',
            maxHeight: '100vw',
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            display: 'block',
            margin: 'auto'
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never change minHeight & minWidth.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I want the div to take the full width of the device and auto-adjust height based on the image resolution. Why is it wrong and how can I do it better?

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting some JQuery:

```
 window.onresize = function() {
    $(".thumb").each(function() {
        this.style.display = "none";
        this.offsetWidth;
        this.style.display= "block";
    })
}
```

Let me know your results!